# Regular Expression for 8 numbers followed by hyphen followed by 1 number

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a Regular Expression that allows 8 numeric digits, follow by a "-", and then  1 more numeric digit.
Eg: `12345678-1`

I tried this `^[\d*-\d+]$`. Need a better solution

Comment: The format that I need 12345678-1.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify exact number of repetitions with `{n}`:

```
^\d{8}-\d$
```

Comment: What happens if I include [ and ] at the beginning and at the end ?

Comment: Then it won't match. But you didn't specify that in the question.

Comment: If you want to also match [ and ] around the expression, you can escape them (since they have special meaning in regex) like this: `^\[\d{8}-\d\]$`

Answer (score 2):

`^[0-9]{8}-[0-9]$` is one way.

`\d` also matches other things like Arabic numerals, so consider its use carefully.